# ElasticSearch: How to set a default mapping to a template

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, default, analyzer

I'm running ElasticSearch version 1.4

I want to create a template that named:

`listener*`

with the following mapping:

Every *string* field will be defined as *not_analyzed*.

Meaning 
`analyzer:not_analyzed`

The main reason for this is my intent to save the data AS IS. (e.g Person ID)

This can be done, but only when I specifically specify the field in its exact JSon structure.

When you have a large JSON structure it is very difficult to maintain.

Is there any way to specify to the mapping that every *string* field will be *not_analyzed* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. After you run it you'll have to delete and rebuild your index, but it will work for all new indices.

```
PUT _template/not_analyzed_template
{
    "template": "*", 
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "template_1": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "match": "*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here's some toy code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/398aab275d48a7a2aac6ba725d5691e1e159496c

Comment: great. I've tried it and it works. BTW, when I've asked this question and got the same answer: use the analyzer "keyword". When I did that, it wasn't like the "not_analyzed", e.g. DATA: "This-Is-My-Data", keyword ANALYZER: word1:"this", word2:"is", word3:"my", word4:"data" which is nothing like "This-Is-My-Data". So my question here is, Is it the only way to achieve what I want? Or is there any other answer to my question above?